# 2006 MacBook Pro no longer booting into Ubuntu after recent update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, macbook-pro, refind

I've been running 20.04 LTS on a dual boot (with rEFInd) 2006 MacBook Pro 2,2 for months with no issues. I ran a recent update and, since then, when I select to boot into Ubuntu in rEFInd, I get a blank screen (no cursor, no nothing) and I don't get the Grub menu (I used to) and I never get to the desktop. Also, when I try to boot off the install DVD, I get the same issue.

I have tried clearing my PRAM, reinstalling rEFInd. Has anyone else run into this issue? If so, is there a resolution? I feel like my last option is to delete the partition and start over :-(

Thanks in advance!

Update: removed references from 20.04.2.0 as this may not be the cause of the issue as noted in the comments. Also, can still boot into OS X so the machine itself is ok.

Comment: The Ubuntu 20.04.2 upgrade came out more than two months ago (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/ shows the date of the ISO release, installed systems got it before that date though) so if it was the 20.04.2 upgrade that came out >2 months ago, are you not upgrading your system regularly intentionally?

Comment: To answer your question, this is not my primary machine. It i's being used for doing some prototyping and experimentation so it may go weeks without being turned on. Not sure how this comment is relevant to my problem...

Comment: You said a *recent* upgrade... and blame something that occurred >50 days ago (Jan-2021), adding doubt to your facts .. specifics provide details and incorrect details just show warnings

Comment: Understood. I don't think it was months that the machine was not on. More like weeks so, to your point, it may not be directly related to the upgrade. However, it was after the Ubuntu updater ran that this behavior started. Could be coincidental...

Comment: Looking at other posts, it looks like this might be related to an issue in an update to Grub2. How do I make a change to Grub2 if I can't get Ubuntu to boot?